# UICollectionView appears black when running the App

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, xcode7

I am using swift 2.0 and xcode 7. I would like to have a vertical collection view with an array of image on my app. However when I run my project the UICollectionView area appears black. I have set the script on my ViewController but I don't what I'm missing. I already have set an identifier and all other stuff. Could somebody help me please. Thanks.

[ViewController Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6iBW.png)

[ViewController error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si8I9.jpg)

Comment: Can you show up your `CollectionViewCell.swift` file ?

Comment: It seems there is an error in the console (something with `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes`), try having a look at that, or alternatively, copy it to your question, maybe that can help in solving the mystery

Comment: i think you might be missing the delegate and data source for collectionView   in the storyboard or xib .

Comment: I think it's fixed now! thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made the UICollectionView display the images although i still need to update the sizes. I've followed @pdobsk advice to look through the error message and it says that i should consider the cell size together with the margin and other stuffs because the cell size is the same size with the collection view.

[error fixed!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnUs0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot about delegates, it's typical error.
Also, try use this example of code

```
class ExampleCollectionView: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let tshirtsArray = ["tshirt_1.png",
    "tshirt_2.png",
    "tshirt_3.png",
    "tshirt_4.png"]

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.tshirtsArray.count
    }

     func collectionView(cv: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
        {
            let cell: UICollectionViewCell = cv.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            let collectionImageView: UIImageView = cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UIImageView
            collectionImageView.image = UIImage(named: self. tshirtsArray[indexPath.row])
            return cell
       }
}
```